# jQuery - Checkbox not being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I'm using checkboxes to toggle the enabled and disabled state of some multi-lists on a registration form. The checkbox is labeled with the category, and the multi-list contains the items that belong to that category.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2.

```
        $('#sch_cat_hockeyschools').toggle(function(ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                $("#type_select_hockeyschools").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#type_select_hockeyschools").removeProp("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#sch_cat_hockeyschools").prop("checked", true);
                $("#sch_cat_hockeyschools").prop("checked", "checked");
            }, function(ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                $("#type_select_hockeyschools option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#type_select_hockeyschools").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#type_select_hockeyschools").prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#sch_cat_hockeyschools").prop("checked", false);
                $("#sch_cat_hockeyschools").removeProp("checked");
            });
```

Sample of corresponding checkbox HTML:

```
<input class="catmark" type="checkbox" name="sch_categories[]" id="sch_cat_hockeyschools" value="1" />General Hockey Schools
<input class="catmark" type="checkbox" name="sch_categories[]" id="sch_cat_springhockey" value="2" />Spring Hockey
```

The problem is that the upon clicking the checkbox, the checkbox does not become ticked or checked; it immediately returns to an unchecked state, which I thought the `stopPropagation()` function would help with. Apparently not. The multi-lists get enabled and disabled as expected, but the checkbox doesn't get ticked.

The result of this problem is that when the form is submitted, the array containing the selected categories is empty; thus, because at least one checked category is a required field in the form, the PHP script that processes the form throws one of my errors which tells me a required field was left blank.

Any ideas on how to make sure that the checkbox actually gets checked, and by extension, POSTS actual data to the processing script?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why not use the default browser behavior for controlling the checkboxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the use of `toggle` -- per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

> The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links
>   will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has
>   been called on the element.

`toggle` itself is calling `preventDefault`, which is stopping the default behavior of the event, checking/unchecking the box.

Rather than toggle, use `bind` or `on` (*see edit note below*) to add a listener for the `change` event, in which you can examine the state:

```
$('#sch_cat_hockeyschools').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        // do stuff for a checked box   
        console.log('check is on');
    } else {
        // do stuff for an unchecked box        
        console.log('check is off');
    }
});
```

[Try it out at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzVA2/).

**EDIT**
Please note, this code shows use of the `on` method, whereas the jsFiddle example uses `bind`. As pointed out by Sam Sehnert, `on` is the preferred method for attaching events with > jQuery 1.7. If you are using an older version of jQuery, use `bind` as in the jsFiddle example.

**Documentation**

- [jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)
- [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.7, you should use the .on method to bind events: http://api.jquery.com/on/. You'll notice this mentioned in the first paragraph of the bind documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I don't actually use jQuery, so that's a helpful note. Edited answer to indicate this.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Sam! I don't often have many cases to use jQuery, and just came from v. 1.4.4, so it's been a gradual game of catch-up for me in getting to know how some of the finer things work, and how everything's changed. Appreciate the help.